# Как сделать так, что бы Django принимал запрос от Telegram Bot'a?

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Требуется сделать так, что бы, когда **пользователь** выбирал первым сообщением `pk(id)` **определённой записи** в **базе данных**, а потом, **следующим сообщением** отправлял что то, надо сделать так, что бы **django** обрабатывал этот запрос и, **перезаписывал** то, что **было в записи**, `pk(id)` которой указал **пользователь** первым сообщением, что отправил пользователь, в ту запись, `pk(id)` которой указывал пользователь.

В интернете вообще ничего не нашёл на счёт этого, кто нибудь знает как реализовать такое?

Если что то не понятно, могу постараться объяснить чуть лучше.

Заранее, **спасибо** всем тем, кто откликнется!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте **Rest API**, *bot* с помощью к примеру **Requests**, отправит запрос на сервер, **Django** его обработает и готово.

UPD: Сам не знаю не **Django**, ни **Rest API** на нем, но делал на **Flask**.
Также вот ссылка на [*Framework*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).